# Extender cable to connect USB flash drive to USB port

Tags: usb, data-storage, cable

I recently learnt about the [Dead Drops project](https://deaddrops.com/), and have found a few dead drops in my city listed on the database. I want to determine whether these dead drops are still extant, and if they are, connect my laptop to them to see what's on them. However, connecting a wall-mounted flash drive directly into a laptop's USB port is pretty awkward to do.

What cables exist out there that could act as an extender for the flash drive, so that one end can be inserted into the drive, and the other into my laptop's USB port so that I can read the contents of the USB drive as normal? This seems a trivially simple piece of hardware, but now that I think about it, I've never heard of anything like this and I don't know what it would be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it happens, it turns out that typing out the question was the impetus I needed to properly think about what I was looking for. Turns out the search term I needed to be looking for was *"male to female USB cable"*, which brings back results for "USB extension cable". I could have sworn I'd already tried searching for the latter, but either way, [Amazon lists several](https://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Delectronics&field-keywords=male+to+female+usb+cable&rh=n%3A560798%2Ck%3Amale+to+female+usb+cable).